# Gmail failing with 'Connection Closed Gracefully' using Indy in Delphi XE on Windows 8

Tags: delphi, gmail, delphi-xe, indy

Roughly 2-3 out of hundreds of Windows 8 clients began getting this message 2-3 weeks ago.

per Wireshark the last transmission before the connection is closed is

**'2.0.0 Ready to start TLS'**

Code snippet:

```
Smtp := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
try
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(smtp);
  try
    Smtp.OnStatus := IdSMTP1Status;
    Smtp.OnWorkBegin := IdSMTP1WorkBegin;
    Smtp.OnWorkEnd := IdSMTP1WorkEnd;
    Smtp.OnWork := IdSMTPWork;
    Smtp.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com'
    Smtp.Port := 487, 565 both tried here;
    Smtp.Username := 'the email@gmail.com'
    Smtp.Password := 'The password'
    // TLS for Gmail, etc
    if UseSSL then // true 
    begin
      Smtp.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
      if Smtp.Port = 465 then
        Smtp.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS
      else
      if Smtp.Port = 587 then
        Smtp.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS
      else
        Smtp.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
      IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Host := 'gmail smtp again'

      IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Destination :=
        Smtp.Host + ':' + IntToStr(Smtp.Port);
      IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Port := Smtp.Port;
    end;
    try
     Smtp.Connect;
     sTempFileName := data1.GetSettingsFileFolder+'\tmp.email';
     EmailMessage.SaveToFile(sTempFileName);
     AssignFile(F,sTempFileName);
     Reset(F);
     iFileSize := FileSize(F) * 128;
     CloseFile(F);
     SysUtils.DeleteFile(sTempFileName);
     StatusForm.SetProgress(0,iFileSize);
     Smtp.Send(EmailMessage);
    except on E:Exception do
      begin
        MessageDlg(E.Message, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Free;
  end;
finally
  EmailMessage.MessageParts.Clear;
  if Smtp.Connected then smtp.Disconnect;
  Smtp.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`2.0.0 Ready to start TLS` is sent in reply to a `STARTTLS` command.  If you are getting disconnected immediately afterwards, then the TLS handshake is likely failing, and you should be getting an exception explaining why it failed.  Double-check your TLS settings.  Also keep in mind that setting the `UseTLS` property may change the `Port` property, so it is best to set `UseTLS` before setting `Port` rather than the other way around.

Also, You do not need to set the IOHandler's `Host`, `Port`, or `Destination` properties.  `Connect()` will handle that for you.

Comment: I made sure UseTLS is before port - double checked TLS settings.  Still failing.  Always on Windows 8.

Comment: Like I said, it has to be a TLS handshake error, and you should be getting an exception raised as such. Is that actually the case? Does Wireshark show any TLS errors during the handshake? Wireshark will not decrypt TLS-encrypted data by default, but it does decypher the handshake itself, which is not encrypted.

Comment: The only error I get is the 'connection closed gracefully'.  No Exceptions.  I didn't see any issue with the handshake.

Comment: What you are describing makes no sense. You originally stated the **last** transmission was the `STARTTLS` reply, which would mean there was no handshake performed. Now you are saying there was a handshake performed, in which case you should not get a "closed gracefully" error during the handshake procedure, it either succeeds or it doesn't. A "closed gracefully" error would make more sense only before the handshake was started or after the handshake was finished. Without seeing the actual Wireshark capture AND the call stack leading up to the exception, this is very hard to diagnose.

Comment: I'll get you the Wireshark Monday.  Sorry for not making sense.

Comment: If I add OnStatusInfo := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1StatusInfo AND showmessage() each status it works.

Comment: Log to a file instead of showmessage or remove the handler, no join.  It fails in the handshake at the server HELO bit otherwise.  This is very odd.

Comment: Again, without seeing the raw traffic from Wireshark (or even from Indy's own `TIdLog...` components), it is very difficult to know what is actually happening.

Comment: Here's two captures via Wireshark.  The working capture is the result of me placing a sleep() call in the Handler for StatusInfo.  The failing capture is without the sleep.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/i66k3rvz1rbqor9/gmail-ssl-wireshark-caps.zip

Comment: In the failure capture, after `TIdSMTP` sent a `STARTTLS` command and the server replied OK, `TIdSMTP` activated TLS and the `IOHandler` sent a TLS "Client Hello" packet, but then `TIdSMTP` sent an unencrypted `QUIT` command afterwards (which Wireshark shows as "Ignored Unknown Record") that caused the server to send a "Fatal Alert" message and close the connection. The `QUIT` is not present in the success capture. `QUIT` is sent when `TIdSMTP.Disconnect()` is called, and that would only happen during a TLS handshake if an exception were raised, as I said in my answer.

Comment: I have updated `TIdSMTP` to not send a `QUIT` command anymore when disconnecting after a TLS handshake failure. But that does not change the fact that an uncaught exception had to have triggered `TIdSMTP` to disconnect in the first place.

Comment: That all makes perfect sense.  What doesn't make sense is how a sleep call fixes it.  It's almost as if the TLS conversation needs slowed slightly or the order of events is incorrect.

Comment: You do not need a `Sleep()`, `TIdSMTP`+SSL/TLS works just fine for most people without such throttling.  Something else is going on.